# get 0 bytes file when using python-django to implementation download operation

Tags: python, django, web, download

django 1.4. I am trying to develop a function to deploy download. I didnt get the right result. I attach my code at below. When I download after click hyperlink, I got a 0 bytes file. The Content-Length is `0` in debug mode. I have read many related questions, I got some clues, but still confused, since I got 0 bytes file after download. can anyone help modify codes below, thx for ur time.

```
   def download_file(request, filepath, filename):
        path_to_file = filepath+"\\"+filename
        serverfile = file(path_to_file, 'rb')
        response = HttpResponse(mimetype='application/force-download')
        response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=%s' % smart_str(filename)
        response['Content-Length'] = serverfile.tell()
    return response
```

Comment: for newer, it is hard to understand something, sometimes, even though it is very easy. I have searched in google and in stackoverflow and doc. I do jobs which is similar as those solutions. but I didnt get the right result. so plz dont downvote again. thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.tell()` gives the current position in a file. Since you haven't read any of the file, your current position will be at position 0.

You could use `os.stat(path_to_file).st_size` to give the file size in bytes. Note that you should also use `os.path.join(filepath, filename)` to get the full (OS-independent) path to the file, rather than concatenating manually.

Comment: path_to_file `"/temp\\data\\New Text Document.txt"`.  `server_file` is `<open file u'/temp\\data\\New Text Document.txt', mode 'rb' at 0x`. and `os.stat(path_to_file).st_size` still `0`. why still fail to get the file? @Danil Roseman

Comment: It works Daniel roseman ,thx.

Comment: I put my codes to CAN_WORK. for newers

Comment: And finally I download a 0 bytes file, because the size of file in server is 0.   :(

Comment: `CAN_WORK` **This is the solution CAN_WORK:**

   **1.** path_to_file = os.path.join(filepath, filename)
   **2.** serverfile = open(path_to_file, 'rb')
   **3.** response = HttpResponse(serverfile, mimetype='application/force-download')
   **4.** response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=%s' % smart_str(filename)
   **5.** response['Content-Length'] = os.stat(path_to_file).st_size